# Reverse Geocoding converting coordinates into address?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Am I missing something completely obvious here?

My intention is to convert the coordinates into an address and insert it into a div

http://jsfiddle.net/sHLG6/1/

Thank you

Comment: (offtopic) ...to give a `value` to an `DIV` element. Is that good?

Comment: please post relevant code in the body of your question - linking to an external site is frowned upon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I saw 3 things that popped out immediately with your fiddle.

1. You never referenced the Google javascript libraries
2. You never called `initialize()` and `codeLatLng()`
3. You used the `value` property on the div element but what you really wanted was the `getAttribute()` method.

[I changed your fiddle so it's working now](http://jsfiddle.net/sHLG6/2/)

For the sake of completeness, the original code was as follows

```
<div id="latlng" value="54.9882,-1.5747"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
var geocoder; function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); } function codeLatLng() {

    var input = document.getElementById("latlng").value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '' + (results[4].formatted_address); + ''
    }); }​
```

Working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="latlng" value="54.9882,-1.5747"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
var geocoder;
initialize();
codeLatLng();
function initialize() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeLatLng() {

    var input = document.getElementById("latlng").getAttribute('value');
console.log(input);
    var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '' + (results[4].formatted_address); + ''
    });
}​
```

Comment: Sorry I did have 1 & 2 in my original code, It was 3 that sealed the deal. Thank you very much.